# Привязка вордпресс к битрикс 24 - смена ответственного

Tags: php, wordpress, битрикс24, contact-form7

Есть форма cf7 на вордпресс. Интегрирована с битрикс (создается лид). Не могу в создаваемом лиде менять ответственного (ASSIGNED_BY_ID по их документации), все равно остаюсь ответственная я , а не нужный мне id.

```
CRest::call('crm.lead.add', [
    'fields'  =>[
        'TITLE' => 'Заявка с сайта ostupchuk.com', 
        'NAME' => $firstName,
        'PHONE' => Array(
            "n0" => Array(
                "VALUE" => $myphone,
                "VALUE_TYPE" => "Мобильный",
            ),
        ),
        'EMAIL' => Array(
            "n1" => Array(
                "VALUE" => $myemail,
                "VALUE_TYPE" => "Частный",
            )
       
        ),
        'STATUS_ID'=> 'NEW',
        'CREATED_BY_ID' => 56,
        'ASSIGNED_BY_ID' => 56,
        'SOURCE_ID' => 'WEB',
        'SOURCE_DESCRIPTION' => $url,
        ],
        'params'  =>["REGISTER_SONET_EVENT" => "Y"]

    ]);
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `'CREATED_BY_ID' => 56,`

Comment: Изначально было без этого, не работало. Это уже по другим советам было добавлено